# how to handle database/table changes in PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, migration, zend-db, database-versioning

Ok so now I have this problem i need to add a "balance" column for my users table. I am using the Zend framework and I was hoping to use this one here:

http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Db_Schema_Manager+-+Rob+Allen#Zend_Db_Schema_Manager-RobAllen-6.Milestones%2FTasks

Unfortunately i suppose it never got into the implementation stage and there's just the header file, the imeplementation file is nowhere to be downloaded.

Would you guys have any suggestion? I don't want to go to 5 mysql database and add manually the column i need - at the same time i don't want to be doing it this way everytime i need to make any db changes. I need something like the zend schema manager component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently using [Akrabat_Db_Schema_Manager](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/akrabat_db_schema_manager-zend-framework-database-migrations/) as a database migration tool. It's written in `Zend Framework` and is pretty straightforward, all database changes should be written in raw `SQL`.

You can also take a look at [Doctrine Migration Tool](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/migrations/en). It allows you to write migrations  using only `Doctrine` objects, thus skipping writing raw `SQL` part. Not sure if it exists for `Doctrine 2.0` though.

More insights [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089817/what-are-some-database-migrations-tools-database-change-management-for-php).

Comment: oooh nice so Akrabat is the continuation of the ZEnd Schema Manager written by the same author.

Comment: @David: exactly! sorry, forgot to mention it